# How many 4x7 arrays of distinct playing cards are there with each row containing cards from the same suit?

Tags: combinatorics

I am stumped on trying to solve this. 
So I know that there are 13 cards in each suit.
Would this work by finding the ways there are to pick 7 cards in a suit, multiply that by 4, then figure out how many ways there are to arrange the 4 rows?

A walk-through of this problem would be very appreciated!

Comment: Multiplying by $4$ won’t do it, because there are more than $4$ possible permutations of the $4$ suits; how many are there?

Comment: Do you care about the order of the cards in a row?  Is a top row with $A234567$ of spades different from a top row of $765432A$ of spades?  That makes a big change to the result.  Do you care what order the suits come in?  That is another factor $4!=24$. 
 Then when you have two independent choices the total comes from multiplying them.  You have $13 \choose 7$ ways to choose the cards in the top row if you don't care about order.  For each of those you have $13 \choose 7$ ways to choose the cards in the second row.  You multiply those to get the number of options in the top two rows.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of multiplying that by $4$, take the $4$th power; you have $\tbinom{13}{7}$ ways to choose $7$ cards for each row.

Comment: So since there are 4 rows of 7 columns, there are (13 choose 7) ways to get 8 cards from each row. Taking the power of 4 would handle the number of rows giving us the final answer? So there would be no need to figure out how many ways there are to arrange the 4 rows?

Comment: @Daniel18 No, it doesn't handle that: For the first row there are $4\times\tbinom{13}{7}$ options. The next row must be of a different suit (why?), so there are $3\times\tbinom{13}{7}$ options, etcetera.

Comment: to the why, I am not entirely sure why. The problem mentioned "with each row containing cards from the same suit", I must've had a typo while explaining my original approach. I see why it would be 4×(13 choose 7) up to 1×(13 choose 7), then summing up each of those.

Comment: Your answer doe not include the factor $4!$ for the order of the suits.  Your comment includes it.